# LINQ to Entites: Filtering list based on another list

Tags: linq-to-entities

Using LINQ to entities, I'm trying to filter a list based on another list.

My first list looks like:

```
IQueryable<FooViewModel> allFoos = from foo in ctx.Foo 
                                   select new FooViewModel 
                                   {
                                     code = foo.Code,
                                     text = foo.Text,
                                     ...
                                   };
```

My second list looks like:

```
IQueryable<FooViewModel> myBars = from bar in ctx.Bar.Include("Baz") select bar
```

There are multiple bazes per bar, and baz has Code and Text properties.

I want to filter allFoos so that I get back only those elements where Code == baz.Code && text == baz.Text

Comment: Could you atleast use foo + bar instead of baz + bar, confusing. :)

Comment: Three different objects - bar has many bazes, but there's no explicit relationship between foo and bar.baz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group selects like this:

```
var query = from x in foos
            from a in bars
            where x.Name == a.Name
            select new FooViewModel { code = x.Code, text = x.Text };
```

You can also of course nest different queries, like replace `from a in bars` with `from a in barQuery.ToList()`.

Comment: That's close:  I had to change the where to 'where bar.Any(b=>b.baz.Code == x.Code && b.baz.Text == x.Text) but I forgot I could have multiple froms in there.

Comment: Sweet! Don't forget to accept answers if you think they are correct / solved your problem, i see that you only accepted half of your questions.

Comment: Apparently I ask tough questions :)